# Calculate average from an array

Tags: c++

I tried to calculate average and when I enter 1 2 3 0 , the average is 2.00 but when I enter 10 20 90 100 0,the average is 227871776.00. I am not able to identify what is going wrong here. I feel like my sum and count is not working properly but I can't figure out why.

```
    double calculateAverage(int numbers[], int count ) 
    {

        int sum = 0;
        double average;
        while (count < arraysize && numbers[count] != 0)
           {
               count ++;
           }
        for (int i= 0 ; i < count; i++)
        {
               sum += numbers[i];
        }
        average = static_cast<double>(sum) /count;
        return average;
    }
```

Comment: Step through it with a debugger. Make sure all your variables have the right values and are initialized.

Comment: How did you invoke `calculateAverage`?

Comment: `arraysize` isn't declared, and usage of `count` doesn't make any sense at all. The code needs more debugging and research on your part to make sure loops are executing the number of times you expect and variable start off at expected values.

Comment: Why even bother with the while loop when you know the count?

Comment: Because I have sentinel value which is 0 and arraysize which is 10;so in order to figure out actual array size.

Comment: Please provide how you called `calculateAverage`

Comment: The average is correct when I enter 1 2 3 and also when i enter 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 but not when I enter 10 20 90 100

Comment: int main()
{
   
   
   int numbers[arraysize];
   int count;


   read(numbers,count);
   
   cout<< "The array: ";
   output(numbers,count);
   cout << endl;
   
   
   cout << "The average is : " << calculateAverage(numbers,count);
   cout << endl << endl;
  
   return 0;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

double calculateAverage(int numbers[], int count ) 
{
    int sum = 0;         //sum is used to add all the values in the array
    double average;    

    for (int i= 0 ; i < count; i++)
           sum += numbers[i];

    average = static_cast<double>(sum) /count;
    return average;
}

int main()
{   
    int lim;                                         //size of the array
    cout<<"Enter the number of elements in array\n";
    cin>>lim;
    cout<<"Enter the values  \n";
    int num[lim];                             //the array is initialized to desired size
    for(int i=0;i<lim;i++)                 
        cin>>num[i];                            //the values are taken from user
    cout<<"\nAverage = "<<calculateAverage(num,lim)<<"\n"; //the array and the size of array is passed to calculate average function  or you can even calculate size of array using (sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[firstelement])
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to include an explanation of the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Why bother even making your own count loop, when you have `std:accumulate`.

```
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>

double calculateAverage(int numbers[], size_t count)
{
    int sum = std::accumulate(numbers, numbers + count, 0);
    return sum / count;
}

int main()
{
    //int numbers[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int numbers[] = {10, 20, 90, 100};
    std::cout << "average is "  <<
        calculateAverage(numbers, sizeof(numbers) / sizeof(int)) << '\n';
}
```

Your code was quite confused. Why pass a count if you're going to count the array anyway? Also 0 is a valid value in the array and so it makes a flawed sentinel value.

Answer (score 0):

### Recreate the code overall

It is hard to understand (your code).

### Mine:

```
double calculateAverage(double numbers[], double count ) 
{
 double sum = 0;
 double average=0;
 for(int counter=0;counter<count;counter++)
 {
    sum+=numbers[counter];
 }
 cout<<sum<<"\n";
 average=sum/count;
 return average;
 }
```

### Explaination:

First the function will take an array of double
and count is how many is there in the array (I tried to stick into your code)
The for loop runs based on the count variable.
the sum adds the value of the element in the array numbers.

Divide to get the average.

Answer (score -1):

`numbers[count] != 0` could produce errors when you have 0 appear earlier in the array. Also, where do you initialize arraysize? It could be null somehow or a very weird number. I recommend calling the numbers length instead. But there's no reason to use the while loop bc you have an array size already known

Comment: I declare arraysize as a constant which is const int arraysize = 10;

Comment: Well, I guess for these purposes it's ok bc you know you'll have a 0 in your array... But I can't the error after glancing at it. I recommend "cout"ing all the variables or debugging it to ensure the values are what you're expecting

Comment: This should be a comment and not an answer